# How can I add the "noatime" flag to my / filesystem without a reboot

Tags: linux, filesystems, fstab

Would the remount command do it if I add the option in /etc/fstab?

Is this this a good idea?

Comment: Good idea? Not always. Prefer `relatime` where available.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why? I've equally read people saying 'prefer `noatime` unless you use the approximately 1 program that thinks it needs `[rel]atime`'. I have no reason to care about access time, so I'm turning it off.

Comment: For me it is always good idea to use `noatime`. I never needed the `atime` attribute value from any single file. I believe this attribute is one of the worst and useless things anyone ever added in Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not anymore. `-o remount,noatime` **was** an effective method of disabling atime without a reboot.

I don't know that I'd say it's a good idea, but if you intend to turn atime off, I don't see what it would be a bad idea either if you have an old enough kernel. According to the man page for mount:

> **MS_REMOUNT**
>
> The following mountflags can be changed: MS_RDONLY, MS_SYNCHRONOUS, MS_MANDLOCK; **before kernel 2.6.16**, the following could also be changed: **MS_NOATIME** and MS_NODIRATIME; and, additionally, before kernel 2.4.10, the following could also be changed: MS_NOSUID, MS_NODEV, MS_NOEXEC.

Comment: Thanks for the input - would I be able to remount and add "relatime" or will that require  a reboot?

Comment: @ckliborn I believe you will have to reboot, but there is no harm in testing a remount just to see.

Comment: I just tried it on several servers with 2.6.32 and it worked on all of them. No reboot needed.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it would work.
Or you can manually add it like:

```
mount -o remount,noatime /dev/sd0 /mnt
```

Comment: With many versions of mount you can omit either the device or the mount point (your choice) and it will lookup the other.

Comment: Who said anything about `/mnt`? OP wanted to remount their `/` fs. I sure hope this command would stop some theoretical naive copy-paste reader from remounting their root filesystem at `/mnt` and thus, presumably, killing their entire session. I'm not about to test that theory, though!

Answer (score 8):

Edit `/etc/fstab` and add the proper noatime entry to your `/` filesystem entry.

Remount the `/` filesystem with:

`mount -o remount,noatime   /`

Comment: How can I verify that the noatime functionality is in place after the remount? Also do I need to worry about anything when remounting /?

Comment: You can look at `/proc/mounts` to see the flags currently in effect.

Comment: Type `mount`. It will show the mount parameters.

Comment: @ckliborn you can also test it by yourself: 1. pick a file that is not being read or written by anybody, 2. check its atime with `ls -lu` and make sure it's some time in the past, 3. read it with `cat` or `cksum`, 4. check its atime again and it should not have changed.